# React Native:JAVA_HOME is set to an invalid directory: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181

Tags: java, react-native, jvm, java-home

When I run my React Native project in Visual Studio Code I've got this error

**ERROR: JAVA_HOME is set to an invalid directory: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181
Please set the JAVA_HOME variable in your environment to match the
location of your Java installation.**

But my path in Environment Variables is correct,why am I getting this error when the path is correct

Comment: What IDE are you using?

Comment: Visual studio code

Comment: @Enigma, what version of windows(7,8 or 10) you are running currently?

Comment: Also, open command prompt and run `echo %JAVA_HOME%`, can you see the path?

Comment: This should likely point to the directory where the binaries actually exist. Make sure the directory actually contains `javac`, `java`, `javaw`, etc.